# Is "Behind The Veil" an accurate representation of secret Mormon rituals?

Tags: religion, lds

In the hidden-camera clip [Behind The Veil: Never-Before-Seen Footage of Secret Mormon Temple Rituals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6udew9axmdM) we supposedly see never-before-seen footage of secret Mormon Temple rituals.

A longer version of the [Endowment Ceremony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ms6ny86rXU4) is also available.

While it might be hard to establish if these particular movies are genuine, is the movie an accurate representation of Mormon "secret" rituals?

Comment: I suspect that if you invite a missionary into your house they will explain it to you.  (I do not mean this as sarcasm either my I know quite a few people in the LDS Church and they are all quite friendly and willing to talk about the church at any opening :)

Comment: Consider asking on http://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What specifically are you asking about?  This question seems rather vague.

Comment: There is an answer to a question about a similar, but not the same, video (by the same youtuber) here at [christianity.stackexchange.com](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57546/did-mormons-have-a-blood-oath-ceremony-before-april-1990). Based on the answer to this other question it is likely that the videos in above question are also authentic.

Comment: Can you briefly describe what rituals are shown in the video, and which aspects of them you are skeptical about ?